# Eclipse: Detail formatter error: <key> cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using the current detail formatter for hashmap

```
key + "-" + value
```

And when I debug the code..

```
import java.util.HashMap;


public class Test1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        HashMap<String, Integer> wordcount = new HashMap<String, Integer>();       

        wordcount.put("foo", 1);
        wordcount.put("bar", 1);

        System.out.println("test"); // set a breakpoint here

    }
}
```

Eclipse said in the variable tab ..

```
Detail formatter error:
    key cannot be resolved to a variable
    value cannot be resolved to a variable
```

Actually I want to see the value of HashMap when the breakpoint stopped at the `System.out.println`...not just `wordcount  HashMap<K,V>  (id=16)`, but with its content.

Comment: It seems that you are using key and value as variables without defining them.

Comment: @BharatSinha, Maybe I have used the wrong method, so what should I do when I want to have a better view to the hashmap's content when I stopped at a breakpoint?

Comment: Can you please post the complete code snippet? Whatever you have provided is not sufficient to identify what's going wrong.

Comment: @BharatSinha, sorry for not posting the complete source code, now updated. What I want is when I break at the System.out.println..I want to view the HashMap in the `Variable` view in the debug perspective. Not just something like `wordcount HashMap<K,V>  (id=16)`

Comment: Post your code where formatter is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detail formatters are for giving you a string representation of an object (and its properties), not for local variables or method arguments. A HashMap has no fields "key" and "value", so your code does not really make sense.

I guess that you confused the detail formatter with some local variables (in a method like HashMap.put()) during another debug session.

To get some correctly working code, it might be the most easy way to first set a breakpoint inside of a HashMap method like put(), and to implement the detail formatter when you hit the breakpoint. That way you can directly verify your new code.

Example detail formatter for HashMaps:

```
StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
buffer.append("entries: ").append(this.size()).append("\n");
for (Map.Entry entry : entrySet()) {
    buffer.append("key: ").append(entry.getKey().toString()).append(", value:").append(entry.getValue().toString()).append("\n");
}
return buffer.toString();
```

This will have the following output for your example:

```
entries: 2
key: foo, value:1
key: bar, value:1
```

Comment: Maybe I have used the wrong method, so what should I do when I want to have a better view to the hashmap's content when I stopped at a breakpoint?

Comment: I've added an example. You should be able to modify that code as you like.

Comment: Thanks, I accepted. I am just wondering why they are not the default, it make debugging more easy.